# Freely write in URL box without refreshing the page or changing domain

Tags: javascript, url

I'm working on a art project about poetry, writing processes and A.I (you can see the ongoing tests here http://82.223.18.239/writing3.php) and I would like to implement a thing I saw on some other website, for exemple here constantdullaart.com/

For exemple I have now : http://82.223.18.239/writing3.php (this is a temporary URL) and I would like to expend the writing to the url box (The after domain part of course). A short looped text could be constantly writen there, or a serie of symbols like on Dullaart website.

I know it can sound technically messy and not elegant at all but, still do you have any idea how to do it ?

Here's our actual code

```
<head>

   <div id="header"></div>
   <div id="body"></div>
   <div id="footer"></div>

   <script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css"> 

        #myTable{ 
           width:"90%";   
           height:"100%";
           overflow:hidden;
           min-width:250px;
           white-space: pre-wrap;
           word-wrap:break-word;
           position:absolute;
           border:solid 0px;
           top:-500px;
           left:320px;
           right:320px;
           bottom:0px;
           font-size:100px;
           font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
           text-align:left

                 } 

        #body{ 
           height:"100%";
           overflow:auto;
           min-width:250px;
             } 

         ::-webkit-scrollbar {display: none;}

    </style> 

</head>

<body>
    <div id="myTable"> <div>

    <script type="text/javascript">  
        var skip = 0;
        function get_data(index) {
            $.ajax({
                url : 'getData.php',
                type : 'POST',
                data: ({"skip":skip}),
                success : function(data) { 
                    if(data && data.trim()!='') {
                        skip = skip+1;
                        showText("#myTable", data, 0, 20);
                    }
                    else {
                        setTimeout(function () { get_data(skip); }, 30000);
                    }
                },
                error : function(request,error)
                {
                    alert("Request error : "+JSON.stringify(request));
                }

            });
        }

        function showText(target, message, index, interval) {   
            if (index < message.length) {
                $(target).append(message[index++]);
                setTimeout(function () { showText(target, message, index, interval); }, interval);

                $('#myTable').css('overflow', 'hidden').bind('DOMNodeInserted', function () {
                this.scrollTop = this.scrollHeight;
                                                                                           });


                                        }
            else {
                get_data(skip);
                $('#myTable').css('overflow', 'scroll')                
                 }
        }

        //var period = 10000; //NOTE: period is passed in milliseconds
        get_data(skip);
        //setInterval(page_refresh, period); 

    </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This whole function and piece of code can be found in the page source. In Google chrome or your favorite web browser right click and select "view page source". You will find this function which does what you want:

```
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    var message = new Array();
    message[0] = ""
    var reps = 2;
    var speed = 666; 
    var p = message.length;
    var T = "";
    var C = 0;
    var mC = 0;
    var s = 0;
    var sT = null;
    if (reps < 1) reps = 1;
    function doIt() {
    T = message[mC];
    A();
    }
    function A() {
    s++;
    if (s > 8) { s = 1;}
    if (s == 1) { document.title = '✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊'+T+'✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊'; }
    if (s == 2) { document.title = '☠️☠️☠️☠️☠️☠️☠️☠️☠️☠️☠️☠️☠️☠️☠️☠️☠'+T+'☠️☠️☠️☠️☠️☠️☠️☠️☠️☠️☠️☠️☠️☠️☠️☠️☠️☠️'; }
    if (s == 3) { document.title = ''+T+'✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊'; }
    if (s == 4) { document.title = '✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊'+T+'⛔⛔⛔⛔⛔⛔⛔⛔⛔⛔⛔⛔⛔⛔⛔⛔⛔⛔⛔⛔'; }
    if (s == 5) { document.title = ''+T+''; }
    if (s == 6) { document.title = ''+T+''; }
    if (s == 7) { document.title = ''+T+''; }
    if (s == 8) { document.title = '✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊✊'+T+'⏳⏳⏳⏳⏳⏳⏳⏳⏳⏳⏳⏳⏳⏳⏳⏳⏳⏳⏳⏳⏳'; }if (C < (8 * reps)) {
    sT = setTimeout("A()", speed);
    C++;
    }
    else {
    C = 0;
    s = 0;
    mC++;
    if(mC > p - 1) mC = 0;
    sT = null;
    doIt();
       }
    }
    doIt();

    (function() {
      var template = '✊☔☁☁☁☠⛔☁☁☁⏳☔⚠☁☁⛔⏳☠☁☁☁☁☁✊'.split(''),
        len = template.length,
        chars, string, i, j, k,
        pushOrHash = typeof window.history.pushState === 'function',

      increase = function(n) {
        return n < len - 1 ? n + 1 : 0;
      },

      update = function() {
        chars = [];
        j = k;

        for (i=0; i<len; i++) {
          j = increase(j);
          chars[i] = template[j];
        }

        string = ['/', chars.join(''), '/'].join('');
        k = increase(k);

        if (pushOrHash) {
          window.history.pushState(null, null, string);
        } else {
          window.document.location.hash = string;
        }

        setTimeout(update, 1000);
      };

      update();
    })();
    </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

        function pageLoad()
        {

        alert('The image of external things possesses for us the ambiguous dimension that in external nature everything can be considered to be connected, but also as separated. The uninterrupted transformations of materials as well as energies brings everything into relationship with everything else and make one cosmos out of all the individual elements. On the other hand, however, the objects remain banished in the merciless separation of space; no particle of matter can share its space with another and a real unity of the diverse does not exist in spatial terms. And, by virtue of this equal demand on self-excluding concepts, natural existence seems to resist any application of them at all. Only to humanity, in contrast to nature, has the right to connect and separate been granted, and in the distinctive manner that one of these activities is always the presupposition of the other. By choosing two items from the undisturbed store of natural things in order to designate them as -separate-, we have already related them to one another in our consciousness, we have emphasized these two together against whatever lies between them. And conversely, we can only sense those things to be related which we have previously somehow isolated from one another; things must first be separated from one another in order to be together. Practically as well as logically, it would be meaningless to connect that which was not separated, and indeed that which also remains separated in some sense. The formula according to which both types of activity come together in human undertakings, whether the connectedness or the separation is felt to be what was naturally ordained and the respective alternative is felt to be our task, is something which can guide all our activity. In the immediate as well as the symbolic sense, in the physical as well as the intellectual sense, we are at any moment those who separate the connected or connect the separate. Georg Simmel from -Bridges and Doors- 1909̿'); 
        }

        pageLoad(); 

    </script>
```

Comment: Oh, okay, thanks. I didn't saw this basic. I must be tired, it's 7:00am here and I didn't sleep. Anyway, thanks !

Comment: No problem, hope you get it sorted.